# How to update file hosted in github through code

Tags: javascript, github

I have a project in github. https://github.com/phantom111/gc . I want to write some code in the same project,  to update the json file within the data folder. How to do this in js/jquery ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in a browser as github does not allow [CORS](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing). However, using a node.js backend of course you can checkout your code, manipulate it, commit and push to github. Maybe something like this works for you: https://github.com/creationix/js-git